# Prove that four points are concyclic

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

We are given four circles :  $C_{1}, C_{2},C_{3},C_{4},$

Such as :

$\;C_{1}\;$ *is concurrent to* $\;C_{4}\;$ *in* $A\;$ & $\;A'$

$\;C_{1}\;$ *is concurrent to* $\;C_{2}\;$ *in* $B\;$ & $\;B'$

$\;C_{2}\;$ *is concurrent to* $\;C_{3}\;$ *in* $C\;$ & $\;C'$

$\;C_{3}\;$ *is concurrent to* $\;C_{4}\;$ *in* $D\;$ & $\;D'$

I have to show that $\;A,B,C,D\;$  lie on a common circle *if and only if*  $\;A',B',C',D'\;$ are concyclic

[So it can be more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeTsD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Direct angle chasing.
Show that $ \angle BCD + \angle BAD = \angle C'D'A' + \angle C'B'A'$

Hence, $ABCD$ is concyclic iff $$ \angle BCD + \angle BAD = 180^\circ$ iff $\angle C'D'A' + \angle C'B'A' = 180^\circ$ iff $A'B'C'D'$ is concyclic.

---

For the details

> $\angle BCD = 360^\circ - \angle C'CD - \angle C'CB = \angle C'D'D + \angle C'B'B$
>  Likesiwse $\angle BAD = \angle A'D'D + \angle A'B'B$.
>  Sum up these 2 angles to get $\angle C'D'A' + \angle C'B'A'$

Comment: Hey Calvin thanks for your help but I still don't see why exactly the sum prove that the four points are concyclic iff the other four points are.

Comment: ABCD is concyclic iff the opposite angles sum to 180. Ditto with A'B'C'D'.

Comment: More clear thanks